# Wordpress mobile responsiveness

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Page RE: fazedigital.co.uk/sem

In WordPress, for an existing preinstalled template. How does one define the ordering of objects within a row as it relates to mobile responsiveness?

Ideally, on small screens, we can fix the text box to load before the image, they are box sitting in the same row.

Thanks
Michael.

Comment: Please add a specific code example so your question can be directly answered.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) in CSS and change the style for each.